# Change origination IP of a packet based on end point IP

Tags: iptables, ip

I Need to change a network packet origination IP address if the destination IP is a particular address.

Here is my setup - i have a VM that is assigned three IP addresses,
one data, one management and a third that is for external access.

The application works using the data IP address.

The application needs to make a call to a web service end point that resides outside the firewall.

The firewall only allows traffic out if the packet is originated from a specific IP address.

Using a test rig, I am able to send a packet out of the network using the external IP address the VM, so i know the firewall is working correctly.

Question restated - Is there a way to change the origination IP address in the packet if the destination IP address is a certain value?

If so, how would this be accomplished?

EDIT:  These are Windows server boxes.

Comment: Set default gateway to firewall, add static routes for data and management.  Or alternatively, if there are very few outside addresses you'll use, add static routes for them pointing to the firewall.  This presumes the 3 interfaces are on different subnets - if that's not true, then take a serious look at your network architecture.

Comment: But if you're really bound and determined to not change routing, you could try something like `iptables -A POSTROUTING -s undesirable-source-ip/32 -d destination-ip/32 -p tcp --sport port -j SNAT --to-source desired-source-ip:port`

Comment: Application certainly opens a socket (somewhere in the code) to make a call to a web service. Configure it so this socket **binds** to the right address. For example, if a call to be done with "ping" program, I'll set source IP address like this: `ping -I source-ip-address destination`.

Comment: VERY sorry folks - i left out a VERY important artifact....   this is a windows machine.